# Terminal command '--version' is showing an earlier version than what I just installed

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I've been having serious issues with npm updating packages.  I've changed the dependencies in my package.json's and ran `npm install`, I've tried deleting the global package but afterwards, when I type `--version`, my Command Line prints the version I just "deleted"), and I've tried installing over my current version.  My command line looks like this:

[image: You can see the latest version of firebase installed at the top, and the earlier version being printed when asked for the current version]

I'd really love to avoid throwing my laptop through a window, but I'm getting close.  Any ideas of why npm hates me?

Comment: Thank you... that was such a simple oversight. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI comes from the npm package `firebase-tools`, not `firebase`.  You should `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest` to get the latest CLI.